# Errors while opening VS 2005 (framework 2.0) solution in visual 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, .net-framework-version

we have a 2005 solution running on framework 2.0. I am trying to convert it into 2010.

I opened it in 2010 and then kept targeted framework version 2.0 for all projects under my solution. While building any project, I am getting bunch of errors for missing reference for DLLs even though I can see all DLLs under references. These DLLs are created by us with run-time framework version 2.0.

**Error 150 The type or namespace name 'ABC' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**